# Each value of each checkbox is a value from an array PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to make each value of each checkbox an item from my array. My array contains column names for a csv file. I want to do this in a loop because I have around 50 column names and would like to save space. Please let me know if I can be more specific. Any help is appreciated; thank you for taking the time to read this.

This code was requested by a confused reader:

Right now I hard-coded the labels for the checkboxes. I want to use the labels inside of the $columns array.
I just would like to know the syntax for having this in a loop. The labels of each checkbox are in an array called $columns:

```
$columns = fgets($handle);
$columns = preg_replace("~[\r\n]+~", "", $columns);
$columns = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\s]/i", "", $columns);

$columns = preg_split("/[\t]/", $columns);
$columns = preg_replace("~[\s]~", "_", $columns);

    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="GUID_enUS" checked />GUID_enUS<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="DateTime" checked />DateTime<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="File_name" checked />File_name<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Customer" checked />Customer<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Operator" checked />Operator<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Shape"  />Shape<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Material"  />Material<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Info_1"  />Info_1<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Info_2"  />Info_2<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Info_3"  />Info_3<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Test_No"  />Test_No<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Material_No"  />Material_No<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Article_No"  />Article_No<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Room_temperature_C"  />Room_temperature_C<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Specimen_temperature_C"  />Specimen_temperature_C<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Rated_temperature_C"  />Rated_temperature_C<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Area_cm"  />Area_cm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Diameter_mm"  />Diameter_mm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Outer_diameter_mm"  />Outer_diameter_mm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Inner_diameter_mm"  />Inner_diameter_mm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Length_mm"  />Length_mm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Width_mm"  />Width_mm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Height_mm"  />Height_mm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Mass_g"  />Mass_g<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Density_gcm"  />Density_gcm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Corner_Radius_mm"  />Corner_Radius_mm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Br_T"  />Br_T<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="HcB_kAm"  />HcB_kAm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="HcJ_kAm"  />HcJ_kAm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="BHmax_kJm"  />BHmax_kJm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Ba_T"  />Ba_T<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Ha_kAm"  />Ha_kAm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="JHmax_kJm"  />JHmax_kJm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Jk_T"  />Jk_T<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Hk_kAm"  />Hk_kAm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="x_"  />x_<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Jx_T"  />Jx_T<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Hx_kAm"  />Hx_kAm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Jmax_T"  />Jmax_T<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Hmax_kAm"  />Hmax_kAm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="Hd_kAm"  />Hd_kAm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="HD2_kAm"  />HD2_kAm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="HD5_kAm"  />HD5_kAm<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="RHD"  />RHD<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="rec"  />rec<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="JC_T"  />JC_T<br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="JCJ95"  />JCJ95<br />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Can you see my driver's license? I take it not; well the same thing applies here; code.

Comment: It was a question about how to do a general thing. I didn't thing something as straight forward and to the point warranted that. I'll add the code. Let me know if you need anything else: water, a beer, or even a driver's license.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I have resolved this issue.

```
<?php foreach($columns as $column) { ?>
      <input type="checkbox" name="columns[]" value="<?php $column ?>" checked /><?php echo $column ?></br>
    <?php }?>
```